# Kafka Stream fixed window not grouping by key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I get a single Kafka Stream. How can I accumulate messages for a specific time window irrespective of the key?

My use case is to write a file every 10 minutes out of a stream not considering the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`Transformer`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html) with a state store and [schedule a punctuation call](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html#schedule-long-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.PunctuationType-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Punctuator-) to go through the store every 10 minutes and emit the records.  The transformer should return `null` as you are collecting the records in the state store, so you'll also need a filter after the transformer to ignore any `null` records.

Here's a quick example of something I think is close to what you are asking for. Let me know how it goes.

```java
class WindowedTransformerExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    final String stateStoreName = "stateStore";
    final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
        Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(stateStoreName),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.String());

    builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);

       builder.<String, String>stream("topic").transform(new WindowedTransformer(stateStoreName), stateStoreName)
        .filter((k, v) -> k != null && v != null)
           // Here's where you do something with records emitted after 10 minutes
        .foreach((k, v)-> System.out.println());
  }


  static final class WindowedTransformer implements TransformerSupplier<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> {

    private final String storeName;

    public WindowedTransformer(final String storeName) {
         this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    @Override
    public Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> get() {
      return new Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>>() {
        private KeyValueStore<String, String> keyValueStore;
        private ProcessorContext processorContext;

        @Override
        public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
          processorContext = context;
          keyValueStore = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
          // could change this to PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME if needed
          context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(10), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (ts) -> {
            try(final KeyValueIterator<String, String> iterator = keyValueStore.all()) {
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                  final KeyValue<String, String> keyValue = iterator.next();
                  processorContext.forward(keyValue.key, keyValue.value);
                }
            }
          });
        }

        @Override
        public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {
          if (key != null) {
            keyValueStore.put(key, value);
          }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {

        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is definitely what I was looking for and I'll mark it as correct, but it also demonstrates that Kafka Stream is not exactly the right tool for the job. I've looked into Apache Beam and it can do it way more easily with a window trigger.